# Tv will be off center if mounting to studs

Tags: fireplace, mounting, studs, hanging, television

I’m trying to mount my Samsung Frame above our fireplace. The placement of the studs makes it so the tv would be about 1 1/4 inch off center if I hang it with the included mount anchored into a stud on each end. If I went directly centered no studs would line up with any of the mounting holes. The tv is 55 lbs.

<s>My main question is 1 1/4 inch off center going to be noticeable for 65” tv, over a 71” mantel, viewed normally from a couch 10-11ft away?</s>

I’ve thought through some of these alternatives:

The Frame comes with a very specific no-gap mount that makes the tv tight to the wall and look like a painting.  We’d like to use the no-gap mount, so that rules out 3rd party mounts. The included mount doesn’t allow for any lateral movement. It does have various mounting holes, but unfortunately but their placement doesn’t span long enough to allow for any studs to be hit while centered. Also wanting to keep the tv tight to the wall rules out mounting plywood across multiple studs and attaching the mount to that.

Update: I was browsing a store and happened to find that a third party makes the exact same no-gap mount. I was hesitant to drill holes in the OEM mount since that'd void the warranty. No qualms drilling the aftermarket mount.

This first picture is the mount lined up with the center of the studs(yellow lines) using the existing holes. You can see the center line is off center. [image: Tv not centered using existing holes]

This next picture is the mount and where the center of the studs(green lines) line up.[image: The mount centered]

If I drill a new hole on the top left side there'll be .56 inches of margin on the left side of the hole. I think that should be ok since the existing holes are only .4 inches from the top. Also since there's a taper, I'll need to move the bottom left hole in a bit and maybe hit slightly off center on the stud. Does that all sound alright?

If I'm trying to follow the manufacturers instructions I should add two sheetrock anchors in addition to the 4 stud holes. If I use anchors in the two center holes(my thumb is covering one) is there enough width between everything? I think it should be alright?

Thanks for your input!!

Comment: There are studs on the front of the chimney?

Comment: Get a different tv mount, one that provides a little side to side adjustability relative to the stud anchor location.

Comment: @whatsisname If you wish to ignore "The Frame comes with a very specific no-gap mount that makes the tv flush with the wall and look like a painting." then sure...

Comment: Show us the mount, please. It's likely that you can put new holes in it for a simple fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

drill holes in the frame where the studs are.  No way would I put a $1000 TV on toggle bolts.

Comment: I just found an aftermarket mount that matches where I can drill holes into and not void the warranty.

Comment: Is the warranty on a hunk of steel really an issue anyway?

Comment: No, I know sometimes to fulfill a warranty a manufacturer requires all OEM equipment be returned so using an aftermarket mount mitigates that.

Comment: Drilled holes in the mount where the studs are and hung it. Tested it and it's super solid! Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

Any TV mount instructions I've read specify that you **MUST** drive the supplied lag bolts into a stud X number of inches. If you do not do this then you cannot hold the manufacturer liable for any injury that your setup might cause.

With that said I would cut out a section of sheetrock from stud to stud which is larger than the TV mount by at least 8 inches vertically and mount a piece of plywood that is as thick as the sheetrock to the existing exposed studs. Behind the plywood I would screw on short studs in the exact location that you require lag bolts for the TV mount.

Finally, mount the TV mount to the faux studs and give it a good slap as you say "that's not going anywhere."

---

If your wall is relatively thick (3/4 inch) and you want to sink your mount to make the TV even more tight to the wall then I would go no thinner than 1/2 inch plywood.

Comment: If this were 8" off (i.e., as far as possible from the studs) or some other serious problem then this would make sense. But it is an awful lot of work for 1-1/4" off center.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Whether it's 1.25", 8", or 2' off it doesn't matter. The serious problem is that OP wants to mount a TV on sheetrock. I'm not here to convince them to live with 1.25" off-center. OP has 2 choices: do it or do it right and I hope to help them achieve the latter.

Comment: OP has made it clear that if they move 1.25" then they hit the studs. Sheetrock over studs if 100% fine, safe and normal. Sheetrock by itself is a definite No.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact OP seems to be trying to rationalize toggle bolts and I am here to supply a firm "No". Given that they are worried about 1.25" off-center then I assume they are the type of person to notice or will uncomfortably live with knowing that it is in fact off center.

Comment: My impression is quite the opposite: That OP seems to be trying to rationalize being 1-1/4" off because they know that stud-mounting is the safe way to go.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact That's a matter of opinion and unanswerable as we are not the ones that have to live with the decision. If they were okay with 1.25" off-center then they would have mounted the TV by now and not asked this question. My impression is that a person who buys a Samsung Frame TV is probably not the kind of person to be indifferent about having something off-center on a 6 inch reveal. Are you sincerely trying to convince me to offer a sub-par solution? You are more than welcome to write your own answer or upvote the other opinions that people posted.

Answer (score 2):

With a TV that big I doubt anyone (except you) would notice 1.25", even with just over 6 total exposed inches on the sides.

When I mounted our 70" Vizio where I wanted it was nowhere near the studs if the entire setup (mount and TV) was completely centered, but I found this mount below which was able to shift left or right I think 9 full inches. So I was able to get 4 total lag bolts in 2 different studs and it turned out great. Doesn't totally hug the wall but it's close enough for me.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07ZYR8F2W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZYR8F2W)

Comment: Wouldn't the viewer be comparing a 4.75"margin with a 7.25" margin on the other side?  That's a 53% difference. (But over 5 feet away...)

Comment: Thanks for your input! Even if no one but me would notice I'd still need to be looking at it everyday and noticing it being off haha